# hist with a single value in Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

When you use the hist function like this:

```
[h x] = hist(data, 1000)
```

works just fine as long as data is longer than one `length(data) > 1`.

But if it is `= 1` then it will do this:

[image]

Where the data spreads itself over -500 to 500. Is there a way to stop it doing this?

Comment: Not sure if I get the question right but anyway...
xlim([xMin xMax])?

Comment: If there is one value in the data, there will be only one peak in its histogram... is this your question?

Comment: Well i want the bins to occur all in the same place instead of spreading themselves over a huge area because its ruining my plots. Is there a way to stop this, i can do it by checking the length before each histogram but that sucks a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form of the function that you're using (`hist(data,1000)`) means that 1000 bins are generated, and MATLAB is defaulting to sizing them with a width of 1 because it has no information about the range of the data (a single value doesn't have a meaningful range).  Here's a blurb from the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html):

> n = hist(Y,nbins) where nbins is a scalar, uses nbins number of bins.

There are a few options that could make it "better" (in quotes, because nobody but you knows what you want):

1) You could use a different form of the function to specify where the bins should be:

> n = hist(Y,x) where x is a vector, returns the distribution of Y among
>   length(x) bins with centers specified by x. For example, if x is a
>   5-element vector, hist distributes the elements of Y into five bins
>   centered on the x-axis at the elements in x, none of which can be
>   complex. Note: use histc if it is more natural to specify bin edges
>   instead of centers.

2) You could limit the number of bins to the number of elements in the data vector, if less than some minimum value:

```
hist(data, min(1000, numel(data)))
```

3) You could check for special cases (like N=1) - you mention that this is not desirable, but using a script/function this isn't a hardship at all, so you may have to clarify why this isn't acceptable.

4) You could scale the x-axis appropriately after plotting (similar to @Parag's answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the range of your data by using [find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function or by logical indexing and then use the `axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])` property described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html)